# Can't type on input box when using e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call a Ajax for search functionality on my website when user press enter (using keyboard) on html input box. To prevent page loading after pressing enter I'm using  `e.preventDefault();` in ajax call but then I can't type of input box. It's working fine but can't type on input box. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var value = $('#txt_name').val();

     if(e.which == 13) {
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"doSearchEnter.php",
        data:{
            'key' : value
             },
        success:function(res){
            $('#showSearchResult').html(res);
             }
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: wait, why don't you prevent default only for return key pressed, so inside the `if` statement???

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry I'm new in Jquery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't type into the `input` because you're suppressing the default behaviour for all keystrokes!

You should only prevent it for the `enter` key:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var value = $('#txt_name').val();
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();    // Moved this into here.
        $.ajax({ ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move youe `e.preventDefault();` inside the condition like:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {


var value = $('#txt_name').val();

if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"doSearchEnter.php",
    data:{
        'key' : value
        },
    success:function(res){
        $('#showSearchResult').html(res);
        }
   });
  }
});
```